# Use of unresolved identifer - IOS Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am at my wits end here, I have been working on this for days and cannont seem to resolve this issue.  I am relitivly new to the coding world, so I am sure this is a rookie mistake, but I just can't afford to waste any more time on this, its been a week almost.

I am writing in XCode 8.3, Swift 3.  I am following tutorials to the letter from Auth0's website.  Before I entered the code I am pasting below, my app would complie, but it would not work. Auth0 said I was mising this code.

I am receiving the following error: **Use of unresolved identifier 'accessToken'** I have no other errors or red !'s but this will not go away. I have tried moving the code around, that doesn't work.  I have tried let, else, if statements, that doesn't work.  I have spent mind numbing hours googling, and still I just can't seem to grasp what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Lock
import Auth0
import SimpleKeychain

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func showLoginController(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Lock
            .classic()
            .withOptions {
                $0.oidcConformant = true
                $0.scope = "openid profile"

            }
            .onAuth { credentials in
                let keychain = A0SimpleKeychain(service: "Auth0")
                guard let accessToken = credentials.accessToken else { return }

                keychain.setString(accessToken, forKey: "access_token")
                self.showSuccessAlert(accessToken)
            }
            .present(from: self)

        Auth0
            .authentication()
            .userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)
            .start { result in
                switch(result) {
                case .sucess(let profile): break
                case .failure(let error): break

                }
            }

        Auth0
            .webAuth()
            .scope("openid profile")
            .audience("https://mycompany.auth0.com/userinfo")
            .start {
                switch $0 {
                case .failure(let error):
                    // Handle the error
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                case .success(let credentials):
                    // Do something with credentials e.g.: save them.
                    // Auth0 will automatically dismiss the hosted login page
                    print("Credentials: \(credentials)")
            }
        }

        Auth0
            .webAuth()
            .scope("openid profile offline_access")
            .start {
                switch $0 {
                case .failure(let error):
                    // Handle the error
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                case .success(let credentials):
                    guard let accessToken = credentials.accessToken, let refreshToken = credentials.refreshToken else { return }
                    let keychain = A0SimpleKeychain(service: "Auth0")
                    keychain.setString(accessToken, forKey: "access_token")
                    keychain.setString(refreshToken, forKey: "refresh_token")
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private
    fileprivate func showSuccessAlert(_ accessToken: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "accessToken: \(accessToken)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}
```

Comment: Which line(s) exactly are causing the error?

Comment: `.userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)` does not have access to the `accessToken` from the  previous `onAuth` closure. it's a completely different scope and you can't be even sure the closures will get executed in the correct order.

Comment: Sulthan, thank you for that info.  I am slightly new to the coding world, could you elaborate on what you mean?  I just need to move that code within the { so its not closed?

Comment: @Maddy  the line that is throwing the red ! error is:.userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)  also, thank you for letting me know about the @ sign, I polarize, I have not posted here before.

Comment: As I said, you need to put the user's username after the `@`. My user is not `Maddy`, it's `rmaddy`. I'm only seeing your message because I came back to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried taking the underscores *_* out of the keys? You are referring to `accessToken` and `refreshToken` but making the keys `access_token` and `refresh_token`. (It doesn't make sense to me that that's the issue, but it is inconsistent.)

Comment: @dfd  I tried what you said but still get the red ! and it won't compile.

Comment: Have you ensured that there are no misspellings or anything else like that anywhere in the app?  By app, I mean did you check all of your .swift files?  Have you tried opening a new Xcode project and copying and pasting each .swift file at a time to pinpoint where the problem is? (I don't know if that's helpful, but it's usually my first go at debugging so I figured I'd share it.)

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast Thank you for the suggestions.  Yes I have checked for misspellings, but I will check again.  What would it have to do with other files, it identifies the file where the issue is?  I took the code and copy and pasted it directly out of Auth0's tutorial, so if they made a spelling mistake, I probably would not have caught it..  I did not know I could copy each file individually.  There are hundreds of files because of the PODS, so that will take me hours, which I don't have.

Comment: Judging as you no longer have spelling errors, I would now check each line of code that you wrote to see where the error is.  You should be able to do this via running one line of code at a time (breakpoints) and/or [enabling zombie objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUeATdeWZKs).  Alternatively, and jokingly, the way to exterminate bugs is with pesticides, which are sold at Home Depot :P

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast  Thank you for the suggestion, I will look at that now.  I like the humor :-)

Comment: Also, I know you're probably still running zombies and breakpoints, but I found [this link](https://learnappmaking.com/unresolved-identifier-understanding-xcode/) that I think will be helpful to you.

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast  Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?  I'll write it up now as an official answer so that you can accept it.  Glad it helped!

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast  it is helping, but I think I am still too new to the coding.  I wouldn't say its resolved yet.

Comment: Is the unresolved identifier message gone?  If not, could you please put a screenshot of the LLDB debugger into your post? Because technically speaking if you have another question, you should post another question on SO and if I don't get to answer it, some other very helpful user will.

Answer (score 0):

Strategies for Debugging Swift Code:

1. Thoroughly investigate LLDB debugger to see what happened
2. Read through existing code (all .swift files that you wrote code in) to check for any spelling errors, etc.
3. Open a new Xcode project and run each .swift file to pinpoint where the error is and/or use breakpoints in your existing Xcode project
4. Enable zombies
5. Code pesticides :P

Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: thank you for your help!.  I have scrapped that project and now tried another way of coding, I am 99% there, but i am stuck on an error i never saw before.  I will create a new post

Comment: @Greg No problem!  If the answer was helpful, please remember to accept it!

Comment: not sure how to do that.  Are you able to help me with my other issue?  I am receiving an Extra argument 'error; in call.  i created a post for it on here

Comment: I also get the unresolved identifyer if I type different code.  I am very lost now.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208215/why-does-this-json-code-not-work-in-swift-3-2?noredirect=1#comment79380679_46208215

Comment: @Greg I'll take a look at your new post, but I don't know JSON, so I probably won't be of much use.  Sorry.  Please accept this answer if it was helpful!

Comment: @Greg You can accept an answer by clicking the grey checkmark underneath the up and down arrows.  It should turn green once you've accepted it.